# How to pipe out data from Python PRNG script similar to /dev/urandom into Dieharder

Tags: python, testing, random

I have created a pseudorandom number generator and I am trying to pipe out the data similar to if someone ran
"$ cat /dev/urandom/"
Specifically, I am trying to pipe out the data to the dieharder RNG test suite.

Typically, reading from urandom to dieharder looks like 
"$ cat /dev/urandom | dieharder -a -g 200"

My program is designed to infinitely generate numbers and outputs them in main as:

```
def main():
 ... # setup and variables
    for _ in iter(int,1): # infinite loop
        PRNG_VAL = PRNG_FUNC(count_str,pad,1) # returns b'xx'
        PRNG_VAL = int(PRNG_VAL,16) # returns integer
        sys.stdout.write(chr(PRNG_VAL)) # integer to chr, similar to /dev/urandom type output
```

Obviously, when I run something like
"$ cat ./top.py | dieharder ..."
the resulting output is just the reading of the contents of the file.

How do I, instead of read the contents of 'top.py', run the file and pipe the output into dieharder similar to reading from /dev/urandom?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a Python question, but a shell question or a basic OS question. But in most POSIX shells, the answer is just `./top.py | dieharder`. The `cat ./top.py` prints the contents of the script to stdout; `./top.py` runs the script and whatever that script prints goes to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I, instead of read the contents of 'top.py', run the file and pipe the output into dieharder…

In `sh`, and most other POSIX shells, you run it the same way you'd normally run it, and pipe that (the same way you're piping the output of `cat`):

```
./top.py | dieharder
```

… or:

```
python top.py | dieharder
```

---

The reason you use `cat /dev/urandom` is that `urandom` isn't a program, it's a file. Of course it's not a regular file full of bytes sitting on the disk, it's a special device file, created by a device driver and mounted via `mknod`, but you don't have to worry about that (unless you want to write your own device drivers); it acts as if it were a regular file full of bytes. You can't easily do the same thing, but then you don't have to.

---

You should read a good tutorial on basic shell scripting. I don't have one to recommend, but I'm sure there are plenty of them.

Comment: Thank you for the response @abarnert, I do not have a strong background with pure shell scripting. If you do have a good tutorial to recommend, I would appreciate it.